How to allow CORS errors with Ngrok?
I have a project that is having issues with CORS in production. In order to reproduce it I have exposed my localhost instance to ngrok. First time I got the CORS error as I expected, but not anymore, do I have to configure something else?

I emptied my browser cache and used incognito.
I have also ran ngrok http --domain=domain-name.ngrok-free.app --response-header-add="Access-Control-Allow-Origin:zero" 8080 just to force the CORS, no luck.

This is the graphql server file that should cause the CORS error:
const requestHandler =
  handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventRequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyWithCognitoAuthorizerEvent>();

const corsMiddleware: middleware.MiddlewareFn<typeof requestHandler> = async () => {
  return async (result) => {
    result.headers = { ...result.headers, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }; // this should avoid the CORS blocked but it's happening in prod.
  };
};

const server = createPrivateServer();

const lambdaHandler = startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler(server, requestHandler, {
  middleware: [corsMiddleware],
  context: async ({ event }) => {
    // context
  },
});

export const handler = middy(lambdaHandler)
  .use(doNotWaitForEmptyEventLoop({ runOnBefore: true }))
  .use(captureLambdaHandler(tracer))
  .use(injectLambdaContext(logger, { clearState: true }))


Why do you think it should produce CORS errors? You allow origin * explicitly, so… should be all good?!

In the ngrok dashboard you can also inspect your traffic with the Traffic Inspector. That way you could see what was different from the first request and the rest of the requests. Then you can modify the request (change headers, etc) and replay the requests all in the Inspector. Docs here: https://ngrok.com/docs/obs/traffic-inspection/

@deceze that’s why I’m testing the error, because it shouldn’t. But I have posted this question bruces I changed that * to X or removed such header and still no CORS error ngrok (whereas in production I do get the error). That’s when I thought ok there must be something in missing.

@stmcallister I’ll definitely check that! Thank you
